# Provide a list comprehension for this?

Tags: python

I need a way to write this list

```
[('a', 0),('a',1),('a',2),('b',0),('b',1),('b',2)]
```

In form of list comprehension

Comment: Can you provide sample code to give a sense of what you are trying to accomplish? And more detail about the problem you are having. There are a number of ways to do this, with many not likely useful to you.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is?

Answer (score -1):

Here you go

```
[(x,y) for x in "ab" for y in range(3)]
#Result: [('a', 0), ('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 0), ('b', 1), ('b', 2)]
```